# Rapidminer Classification

Tags: rapidminer, multilabel-classification

I am trying to solve a simple classification problem where the label has 12 different levels and need to classify each example into one of these 12. However, I want my output to look like refer the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/49USG.png

Here; assuming that I set a confidence threshold of 20%; I want my output to contain all the labels for each id which are above 20% and ordered (highest confidence first). If none of the labels are above 20%; then a default label. 
More specifically, are there any existing operators in Rapidminer which could give such an output?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the `Apply Model` operator runs, it produces new special attributes corresponding to confidences for the individual values of the label attribute. So if the label has values `one, two, three`, three new attributes will be created `confidence(one), confidence(two), confidence(three)`. It would be possible to use the `Generate Attributes` operator to work out some logic to decide how to really classify each example. It would also be possible to use the `Apply Threshold` operator (with `Create Threshold`) to do something similar. It's impossible to give any more guidance unless you post a representative example with data.